# How do command-line tools have their own autocomplete list?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

How does Bash in Ubuntu know a tool's specific list of actions?

For example if I type **apt-get** and tab twice I only see remove, update, upgrade ...etc, but not the actions for another command or the files in the current directory.

I'm developing a command-line tool in Go and would like to provide this feature for the distros that support it.

Comment: I removed "ubuntu" from your title and tags since this is better as a more general question (the answer isn't specific to any distro).

Comment: Great question, I've often wondered this, but never took the time to look it up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does this using bash v4's completion features. The completion code for `apt-get` is provided by the `bash-completion` package and located at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get`. Applications that have completion and are not part of the base `bash-completion` package place their completion scripts in `/etc/bash_completion.d`.

The completions are loaded via sourcing `/etc/bash_completion`. Exactly where this is done will vary depending on Debian or Ubuntu versions. That in turn will source everything in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` and `/etc/bash_completion.d`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. So the implementation no only varies from Debian to Ubuntu, but also in each version of the same distribution?

Comment: @Amgad It works the same way on all distributions. The only differences are where the files are located, and perhaps some default settings.